# Merge two custom javascript functions

Tags: javascript

This is the first function:

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function(){

    var self = this,
        json = {},
        push_counters = {},
        patterns = {
            "validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
            "key":      /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
            "push":     /^$/,
            "fixed":    /^\d+$/,
            "named":    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
        };


    this.build = function(base, key, value){
        base[key] = value;
        return base;
    };

    this.push_counter = function(key){
        if(push_counters[key] === undefined){
            push_counters[key] = 0;
        }
        return push_counters[key]++;
    };

    jQuery.each(jQuery(this).serializeArray(), function(){

        // skip invalid keys
        if(!patterns.validate.test(this.name)){
            return;
        }

        var k,
            keys = this.name.match(patterns.key),
            merge = this.value,
            reverse_key = this.name;

        while((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined){

            // adjust reverse_key
            reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$"), '');

            // push
            if(k.match(patterns.push)){
                merge = self.build([], self.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
            }

            // fixed
            else if(k.match(patterns.fixed)){
                merge = self.build([], k, merge);
            }

            // named
            else if(k.match(patterns.named)){
                merge = self.build({}, k, merge);
            }
        }

        json = jQuery.extend(true, json, merge);
    });

    return json;
};
```

This function to serialize the form's values but the problem of this function that it's not getting the value of the unchecked inputs because that I make this function:

```
jQuery.fn.mySerialize = function() {
    var $container = jQuery(this),
        $checkboxes = $container.find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
            jQuery(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0).prop('checked', true);
        });

    var serialized = ($container.serializeObject());

    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).prop('checked', jQuery(this).val() == 1);
    });

    return serialized;
};
```

And it's working as I need by directly using `mySerialize` function now I want to merge the edits that I make at `mySerialize` function to the `serializeObject` function because I failed to do that directly into `serializeObject` function because that I created the `mySerialize` function.

Thanks in advance and really hope anyone helps me on this.

Comment: why merge? would you only ever use `serializeObject` on elements that have checkboxes as children? seems like you want to put the `$checkboxes` code into `serializeObject` .. why are you having problems doing that?

Comment: i.e put lines 2-5 of `mySerialize` before `this.build =` ... and put lines 9-11 just before `return json` (though, json is a poor choice of variable name, since it isn't JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I do like you say thank you very much for your time, My mistake that I put the codes inside the jQuery.each, Thank you again.

Comment: @John is this one resolved?  Care to post an answer and accept it?